# how can i stop this counter and put the final value in databases using react js axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

i need a help please i am new in reactjs
how can i stop this counter and put the final value in databases using  react js axios

the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-counter-c2cei?file=/src/index.js:24-43

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Counter() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => setCounter(counter + 1), 1000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Counter: {counter}</h2>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCounter(0)}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function runCallback() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(runCallback, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Where are you attempting to pause/stop the timer to do anything with its value? This question feels a bit incomplete.

Comment: @DrewReese I need any value when i stop  the timer for put the stop value in the databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "stop" the timer and do something with the current `counter` value then I have some suggested tweaks to allow your timer to be paused/stopped and issue a side-effect with the current state.

1. Modify the `useInterval` hook to *always* run the cleanup function when the dependency updates. You can also simplify the interval callback, i.e. pass the callback ref's current value.

   ```
   function useInterval(callback, delay) {
     const savedCallback = useRef();

     useEffect(() => {
       savedCallback.current = callback;
     });

     useEffect(() => {
       let id;
       if (delay) {
         id = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay);
       }
       return () => clearInterval(id);
     }, [delay]);
   }
   ```
2. Add a `delay` state to your component that you can toggle between `null` and `1000`.

   ```
   const [delay, setDelay] = useState(1000);
   ```
3. Use a functional state update in your `setCounter` state updater to avoid stale state enclosures.

   ```
   useInterval(() => setCounter((c) => c + 1), delay);
   ```
4. Add a button to toggle the interval running.

   ```
   <button
     type="button"
     onClick={() => setDelay((delay) => (delay ? null : 1000))}
   >
     {delay ? "Pause" : "Start"}
   </button>
   ```
5. Use an `useEffect` hook to run a side-effect to do what you need with the `counter` state when the interval is paused/stopped

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     if (delay === null) { /* do stuff */ }
   }, [counter, delay]);
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-can-i-stop-this-counter-and-put-the-final-value-in-databases-using-react-js]

Full code:

```
function Counter() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [delay, setDelay] = useState(1000);

  useInterval(() => setCounter((c) => c + 1), delay);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (delay === null) { /* do stuff */ }
  }, [counter, delay]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Counter: {counter}</h2>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCounter(0)}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setDelay((delay) => (delay ? null : 1000))}
      >
        {delay ? "Pause" : "Start"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let id;
    if (delay) {
      id = setInterval(savedCallback.current, delay);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

store setInterval id in a useState and return a function that clears interval, please check as answer if this solves your issue :)

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Counter() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const [stopInterval] = useInterval(() => setCounter(counter + 1), 1000);

  const onStopCounterClick = () => {
     stopInterval();
     // axios.post(...., {counter}); you can send here
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Counter: {counter}</h2>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCounter(0)}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={onStopCounterClick}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function runCallback() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(runCallback, delay);
      setIntervalId(id);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);

  const stopCounter = () => {
     clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  return [stopCounter];
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement);
```